# display tooltip bottom of the button when hover state

Tags: html, css

Here is my website [link](http://maverick-sunglasses.myshopify.com/)

In first row of the button,, when hover, the tooltip displayed and it hidden the some background image.

So i need to display bottom of the button for only first row.

I tried this css:

```
.swatch .tooltip, .bullet li .tooltip{
  text-align:center;
  background:gray;
  color:#fff;
  bottom:80%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  left:-23px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  /* Make it invisible by default */
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  /* Animations */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  z-index: 10000;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.swatch .tooltip:before, .bullet li .tooltip:before {
  bottom:-20px;
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
/* CSS triangle */
.swatch .tooltip:after, .bullet li .tooltip:after {
  border-left:solid transparent 10px;
  border-right:solid transparent 10px;
  border-top:solid gray 10px;
  bottom:10px;
  content:" ";
  height:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-13px;
  position:absolute;
  width:0;

}
.swatch .swatch-element:hover .tooltip, .bullet li:hover .tooltip {
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -khtml-opacity:1;
  -moz-opacity:1;
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
       -o-transform:translateY(0px);
          transform:translateY(0px);
}
.bullet li .tooltip{left:-30px;font-family:lato;font-size:15px;}
```

May i know, how can i do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will ask for password in your given link

Comment: hi @ketan: here is the image in current state  http://s27.postimg.org/gb86hcsf7/untitled.png ..  i need to show bottom of the button..

Comment: Please provide all the code required to replicate the issue in the question itself.

Comment: sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ronluna/6sgLagrr/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the position of the tooltip.

I've changed the arrow direction (from *border-top* to *border-bottom*):

```
border-bottom-color: #000;
border-bottom-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
```

And I've changed the position of the tooltip itself:

```
bottom: -60px;
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/zbbf7cp2/3/

If you want it to affect only the first row, apply a class on these elements or, if you they're grouped into rows (different element) add a class on the first row so you can then target the children.

Comment: i posted sample fiddle for your understanding.. for me it shows like this, http://s15.postimg.org/gy0p5brp7/untitled.png.. i think do some translate.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## dhtmltooltip{

```
position: absolute;

width: 150px;

border: 2px solid black;

padding: 2px;

background-color: lightyellow;

visibility: hidden;

z-index: 100;

/*Remove below line to remove shadow. Below line should always appear last within this CSS*/

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=gray,direction=135);

}
```

[enter link description here](http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm)